# Trick to finding length of parametric curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was giving the parameters of the curve:

$x = 2cos(2t)$

$y = 2sin(2t)$

and $z = 1$, where $ 0  \leq t \leq 10 \pi$

This curve describes a cylinder in the $z$ direction, and seems very straight forward, where I simply integrate the length of the derivative from $0$ to $ 10 \pi$, to get a length of $40 \pi$. However, my professor said that there is a trick to this problem, so is there something that I'm failing to understand from this?

Comment: If you mean a cylinder with $z$ increasing with $t$, then you should have $z=t$ instead of $z=1$?

Comment: @flawr, Sorry, no I misquoted the statement then. The curve is simply located along the $z$ axis. $z$ should equal $1$

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=1$, then you just have a circle of radius $r=2$. And because $0\leq t \leq 10\pi$ you go around the circle $10$ times. The circumference of the circle is $2\pi r = 4\pi$, therefore the total traveled length is $2\pi r \cdot 10 = 40\pi$.